# Keyword async error running shub command

Tags: python-3.x, scrapinghub

I got my spiders ready, and now I want to deploy them to scrapinghub. 
I've succesfully installed shub running `pip3 install shub`. Im using python 3.7.

But when I run shub, I get a syntax error. I can see that this issue should be fixed in the latest shub release version 2.8. Am I doing something wrong, or is the bug still not fixed? You can see the bug here https://github.com/scrapinghub/shub/pull/327
The error looks like this

```
shub
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/shub", line 7, in <module>
from shub.tool import cli
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shub/tool.py", line 57, in 
<module>
command_module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shub/deploy.py", line 27, in <module>
from shub.image.upload import upload_cmd
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shub/image/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
command_module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shub/image/deploy.py", line 61
apikey, insecure, async):
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you installed a cached version? Did you try:

`pip install -U shub`

?

Update: The fix is included in 2.8.1

Comment: @jonask The fix wasn't included in 2.8.0. 2.8.1 has just been released.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!